# How to find the class-file on case insensitive filesystem?

Tags: perl

Simple test case (for the demonstration of the problem):

```
mkdir -p ./lib1/Class ./lib2/Class
touch ./lib1/Class/Name.pm ./lib2/Class/NAME.pm
```

So, have:

```
./lib1/Class/Name.pm
./lib2/Class/NAME.pm
```

Need search for the right file in the case-insensitive filesystem (OS X's HFS+).

The following works on case-sensitive filesystem,

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use 5.014;
use strict;
use warnings;

my @DIRS = qw(./lib1 ./lib2);

for my $class ( qw(Class::Name Class::NAME) ) {
    my $file = findClassFile($class);
    say $file;
}

sub findClassFile {
    my($file) = @_;
    $file =~ s|::|/|g;
    $file .= ".pm";

    for my $dir (@DIRS) {
        return "$dir/$file" if( -e "$dir/$file" );
    }
    return undef;
}
```

and prints

```
./lib1/Class/Name.pm
./lib2/Class/NAME.pm
```

on the OS X, it prints incorrectly:

```
./lib1/Class/Name.pm
./lib1/Class/NAME.pm
```

How to find on the OSX's insensitive filesystem the correct filename?

Ps: *Now only comes to my mind write and recursive routine with `opendir/readdir/chdir` and checking the filenames what are comes from `readdir`. Not to shabby... Exists some more easy way?*

Comment: What does the '-e' part in  "if ( -e "string" ); ?

Comment: @wald : -e: checking the existence of the file... `perldoc -f -X`

Comment: What's wrong with `readdir` (or `File::Find` if you want something recursive)?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot nothing is wrong - only isn't very nice. Is **IS** solvable, but hoped in some more elegant, shorter, faster, nicer (choose some) solution.. ;) (or already ready/done cpan-module).

Comment: https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Iterator::Rule has a nice API.  It's worth checking out.

Answer (score 0):

My current solution is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use 5.014;
use strict;
use warnings;

my @DIRS = qw(./lib1 ./lib2 /Users/me/tmp/lib3);

for my $class ( qw(Class::Name Class::NAME CLASS::name Class::Namex) ) {
    my $file = findClassFile($class);
    say $file // "Not found $class";
}

sub findClassFile {
    my($classname) = @_;
    my $file = ($classname =~ s|::|/|gr) . ".pm";
    for my $dir (@DIRS) {
        return "$dir/$file" if( FileExists("$dir/$file") );
    }
    return undef;
}

sub FileExists {
    my($path) = @_;
    my $curr = $path =~ m|^/| ? "/" : ".";
    for my $part (split '/', $path) {
        next unless $part;
        opendir(my $dfd, $curr) || return undef;
        my @files = grep {/^$part$/} readdir($dfd);
        closedir($dfd);
        return undef unless( @files );
        $curr .= "/$part";
    }
    return $curr;
}
```

what prints:

```
./lib1/Class/Name.pm
./lib2/Class/NAME.pm
/Users/me/tmp/lib3/CLASS/name.pm
Not found Class::Namex
```

so - it's working, only don't like it.. ;)